# Value of such that $f (x)$ has a minimum at $ x=1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the value of $b$ st $f (x) $ has a minimum at $x=1$ let $f (x)=-x^3+\frac {b^3-b^2+b-1}{b^2+3b+2}.\text {.for }x\in (0,1) $ and $f (x)=2x-3$ for  $x\in [1,3)$. Sorry for not using begin cases as I have forgot how to use it. So coming at the question the function will achieve minimum of for all $x\in (c-h,c+h)-{c} $  we have $f (x)>f (c) $ . Also the dunction should be continuous. . Now for first condition the value at $x=1$ is $-1$ thus in its vicinity $-1+\frac {b-1}{b+2}>-1$ thus I get $b\in (-\infty,-2)\cup(1,\infty) $

Comment: I wonder why you didn't say find value of $t$ st......

$f(x) = - x^3  + t$ on $(0,1)$......

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)$ must be continuous at $x=1$

as $f(1)=-1$ we need that

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x)=-1\to \frac{b^3-b^2+b-1}{b^2+3b+2}=0\to \frac{(b-1)(b^2+1)}{(b+1)(b+2)}=0\to b=1$$
but for $b=1$ the function becomes

$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{align}
-x^3 & \text{  if } 0<x<1\\
2x-3 & \text{  if } 1\le x < 3\\
\end{align}
\right.
$

If we want $f(x)$ continuous then $x=1$ is a minimum for any $b\ne -1\land b\ne -2$

Hope this helps